# How to Consume (SOAP) web service through NODEJS?

Tags: node.js, wsdl, webservice-client, node-request, node-soap

I am fairly new to nodejs, but i have some working experience in APIs, I can work with REST. But SOAP is a bit tricky.

I would like to consume a SOAP web service through nodejs. I am using [soap-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap)

In my server.js file i have the following script - im not getting any errors - it runs...but

```
const soap = require('soap');
const url = 'http://ws.dev.freepaid.co.za/airtimeplus/?wsdl';
const args = { user: ****, pass: '****' };

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {

  client.fetchProducts(args, function(err, result) {

         if(err) 
         console.log("error:", err)
         else 
         console.log(result);
  })
});
```

In the terminal after running command 'node server.js', I get the following response...

```
{ 
reply: {
attributes: { 'xsi:type': 'tns:fetchProductsOut' },
status: { attributes: [Object], '$value': 0 },
errorcode: { attributes: [Object], '$value': '110' },
message: { attributes: [Object], '$value': 'request not defined' },
balance: { attributes: [Object], '$value': 0 },
products: { attributes: [Object] } 
    }
}
```

From this point, i'm not sure how to handle it.

What do I do in order to consume an operation?

In the [WSDL](http://ws.dev.freepaid.co.za/airtimeplus/?wsdl), fetchProducts is an operation that will take in two params 'user' & 'password'.

I can run this operation in SOAP UI and POSTMAN, i get the responses i want. But i need to get these same responses in node.

How to?

Comment: Can you add the successful xml-request from postman/soap-ui, please?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:tns="http://ws.dev.freepaid.co.za/airtimeplus/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tns:fetchProducts>
       <request xsi:type="air:fetchProductsIn">
   <user>****</user>
   <pass>****</pass>
   </request>
   </tns:fetchProducts>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Comment: However, I managed to get the correct response. 

I also inspected the POST body and it seems the problem was there - I omitted a body tag of "Request". 

For -  const args, I added the following 

const args = { request { user: ****, pass: '****' } };

Comment: Thank you for the quick response - I will be back (",)